# How can I export each row of a DataFrame to a different worksheet in the same workbook?

Tags: python, pandas, export

I am trying to export each row of a DataFrame into a different worksheet of the same excel file, naming each after it's index. My method is not working because it just exports the workbook with just the last row as a sheet.

I have tried changing the parameters for export and changing the name of the sheet as a format to the index with %s. I tried exporting them with the same format to different workbooks and it worked, which exported hundreds of different Excel files with the names I wanted.

```
f1 = pd.merge(a,b,how = "outer", on = "Column1")
...
for index, row in f1.iterrows():    
    save = row.to_excel("%s.xlsx" %index[:6], sheet_name = "%s" %index[:6])
```

No error messages, and I expect a single Excel file with several sheets named after each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,5], [4,5,6,12],[7,8,9,11]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        sheet_name = "Sheet {}".format(index)
        row.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html